# Haskell - Quadratic Formula

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

Today I started reading a book regarding Haskell and told myself I give it a try to implemement something basic such as the "quadratic formula".

```
quadHelper a b c op = (-b `op` sqrt (b * 2 - 4 * a * c)) / (2 * a)
quadFormula a b c = [quadHelper a b c (+)] ++ [quadHelper a b c (-)]
```

Unfortunately, my first implementation doesn't work as expected and I get `[NaN, NaN]` as a result for `quadFormula 5 6 1`

Does anyone have an idea what I've missed?

Comment: There is a typo in the formula (`b * 2` rather than `b ^ 2`).

Comment: awesome! I could swear I was checking the formula at least 3 times but couldn't see the typo ...

Comment: You are aware this won't work for equations like `x^2 + 1` (`quadformula 1 0 1`), right?

Comment: It's a good habit to always add a type signature for top-level functions, so to help the compiler produce better type error messages when inevitably we get them. Also `[x,y]` is more readable than `[x]++[y]`.